# Compare 2 JSON-files and create a new key if values match

Tags: json, dictionary, parsing, jq

I have 2 sets of JSON-files looking like below, `data-A.json` and `data-B.json`.

I need to somehow compare the key `URL` in `data-A.json` with the same key in `data-B.json`. Where there is a match take data from the key `Position` in `data-A.json` and write to new key `PreviousPosition` in `data-B.json`. If there is no matching `URL`, write a null value for this new key in `data-B.json`

Please see examples:

**data-A.json**

```
[
    {
        "Position": "1",
        "TrackName": "One hit wonder",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/xyz123"
    },
    {
        "Position": "2",
        "TrackName": "Random song",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/123qwe"
    },
    {
        "Position": "3",
        "TrackName": "Dueling banjos",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/asd456"
    }
]
```

**data-B.json**

```
[
    {
        "Position": "1",
        "TrackName": "Rocket",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/nbs678"
    },
    {
        "Position": "2",
        "TrackName": "Dueling banjos",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/asd456"
    },
    {
        "Position": "3",
        "TrackName": "One hit wonder",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/xyz123"
    }
]
```

(desired) **data-B.json**

```
[
    {
        "Position": "1",
        "TrackName": "Rocket",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/nbs678",
        "PreviousPosition": null
    },
    {
        "Position": "2",
        "TrackName": "Dueling banjos",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/asd456",
        "PreviousPosition": "3"
    },
        {
        "Position": "3",
        "TrackName": "One hit wonder",
        "URL": "https://domain.local/xyz123",
        "PreviousPosition": "1"
    }
]
```

I have done some mediocre attemps to solve this using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) with no luck. Also tried some PowerShell and Python but I just can't figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a straightforward, two-line solution is what you're looking for, then jq is a good choice:

```
(INDEX($A[]; .URL) | map_values(.Position)) as $dict
| map( .PreviousPosition = $dict[ .URL ] )
```

This is perhaps more straightforward than it looks, as the expression in the first line is a commonly found idiom (namely `INDEX(...) | map_values(...)`) for creating a dictionary.  In the first line, it is assumed that $A holds the JSON in data-A.json.

The second line just applies the lookup rule specified in the question.

The only tricky bit here is getting the command-line invocation right.  The following will suffice:

```
jq --argfile A data-A.json -f program.jq data-B.json
```

where program.jq contains the above two-line program.

Comment: Thank you, works exactly as I wanted it to! A quick follow-up question: is it possible to copy more keys than just the `Position`? Let's say I also have a key called `customValue` in `data-A.json` that needs to be copied to a key with the same name in `data-B.json` based on the same rule as above. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You could create and use a second dictionary in the same way as shown here, but it would probably be more efficient to create a single dictionary.